# Should I create a Class object?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I am a beginner in C++. I am working on a project currently which involves multiple classes. I have a question regarding this, I have 2 classes `A` and `B`, `class B` has 2 methods `send` and `registerrecievehandler` which class A uses. I don't understand when it should be inherited. My thought process is as it is a function call should I just make the methods of `class B` as `static` ? I don't think so I need to create a class object of type `B` as it's just a function call.

My question is should `class A` inherit `class B`?

```
class A{
 //member variables of this class
public:
  senddata(string data){
     send(data)
  }

  createdata(){
    // does something here
    senddata(data); //just an example
 }

  receive(){
     registerrecievehandler(f);
  }

}

class B{ //networking stack
  func_ptr* p
  //other members of this class
public:

 //many member functions here

 
 send(string data){
    //do something
 }
 
 registerrecievehandler(f){
     p =f;
 }

}
```

Comment: If class A contains no data, then why does it exist? From the code above class B makes sense but class A does not.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ makes sense if it's a pure virtual interface

Comment: This question seems like it doesn't understand composition. Or the difference between a class and an object. Or how if it's really "just" function calls, it's okay to have free functions. Preferably in a namespace.

Comment: @john Sorry I didn't mention this class A and B mentioned here are just partial classes I showed here , I didn't want complicate the code here.Class A has some function which creates the data and it has it's own members. Class  B(network stack)  is separate class which has  data members as well.

Comment: Create a proper [mre]. If the code you show can't adequately demonstrate your problem, how are you expecting to get any assistance?

Comment: I did make the changes

Answer (score 5):

> My question is should class A inherit class B ?

The general answer is, "it depends". However, I will use the information in your question and best practices to answer your question. We can even rephrase the question to "*When should a class inherit another class?*"

Information we have:

- We have two classes, A and B
- Class B has 2 member functions which are going to be used in class A

The answer with this much information is pretty simple. No. There is no point in doing inheritance here. Why? Because `A` is *using* `B`. To use `B` it doesn't need to inherit `B`.

What do the best practices say? Before answering this, let's keep one thing in mind that an answer or a best practice is not applicable everywhere and in every case. Sometimes we have to think about our problem and create our solution which is best for the problem at hand.

The best practice is to "minimize coupling" and dependencies between your classes. Your classes / interfaces etc should be weakly linked to each other. This not only leads to a better design but makes the code easier to modify and maintain and opens up opportunities for testing and other things. It may even lead to better performance, not necessarily though. Inheritance is the strongest form of relationship two classes can have and it leads to strong coupling. So, if you `A` inherits `B`, there is a good chance that if you modify `B`, you may need to modify `A` as well thereby increasing your work and making it hard to maintain your code.

Reasons not to use inheritance in your case:

- You don't have any protected members in `B` that you want to access in `A`
- You don't have any `virtual` functions that you want to specialize / override in `A`
- `A` doesn't remotely feel like it is something similar to `B`
- `A` wants to use `B`, so it should contain `B` (composition)

When should inheritance be used?

Inheritance is used when you want to express a "IS-A" relationship, as in, Car IS-A Vehicle. I know this is very simple and it is difficult to find or express such relationship when developing real software but I am just making a point.

> My thought process is as it is a function call should I just make the methods of class B as static ?. I don't think so I need to create a class object of type B as it's just a function call.

This part may lead to opinion based answers.

You can make them static and use them like that, but in C++ we have a much better facility we can use in such cases: `namespace`.

You can make `B` a `namespace` and then use the functions inside it from wherever you want.